# Check sql server instance conectivity

Tags: sql

Our daily checks involve checking all servers in our network for conectivity. At present we manually log on to each server and their instance to check.

Is there a tool that will automaticaly check all servers and their instances on the network or can an sql  script be coded to do this?

Thanks
Andy

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [ServersAlive](http://www.woodstone.nu/salive/features.asp).  It's worked well for me in the past at monitoring a big range of services.

Comment: I've been using ServersAlive for a couple of years now.  Keep in mind that the native SQL task doesn't work well against newer (SQL 2008+) versions of SQL Server.  But you can run a SQL Script using SQLCMD easily enough.  The upside is that you can start the services is they are down as well.

Answer (score 1):

Nagios is a well-liked monitoring system, and it comes with plugins for many aspects to monitor - eg memory, network, CPU, servers, etc.

There's [one for SQL Server](http://support.nagios.com/knowledgebase/faqs/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=52&catid=35&faq_id=156&expand=false&showdesc=true) too:

> Use the plugin "check_mssql_health" to
>   monitor MS SQL Servers. Unlike other
>   plugins, it not only checks for a
>   successful connection, but gets > 20
>   useful metrics

Answer (score 0):

If you have enterprise needs, Microsoft's SCOM will monitor availability and performance for SQL Server - and loads of other Microsoft/Wintel products as well. It's competitively priced. Other monitoring solutions are available from the likes of BMC, HP etc

At a budget level, Idera's admin tool kit comes with a SQL Server ping function that will run every x minutes from the system tray - it's USD 295 per install.
http://www.idera.com/Products/SQL-toolbox/SQL-admin-toolset/

Finally, why not try to script one yourself - a dedicated SQL Box, running SQL jobs to query other SQL Server's availability - and using database mail if there's a problem.